# How should I compute this proposal kernel density?

Tags: sampling, density-function, monte-carlo, metropolis-hastings, numerics

Let $d\in\mathbb N$ and $$u(x,y):=\beta+(1-\beta)\prod_{i=1}^d\psi(y_i-x_i)\;\;\;\text{for }x,y\in[0,1)^d,$$ where $\beta\in[0,1]$, $$\psi(x):=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\varphi(k+x)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in(-1,1)$$ is the density of the wrapped normal distribution with mean $0$ and standard deviation $\sigma>0$ and $\varphi$ is the density of the normal distribution with mean $0$ and standard deviation $\sigma$.

> In my application, $u$ is occurring in a proposal kernel (with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1)^d$) for the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm and I need to compute the fraction $\frac{u(x,y)}{u(y,x)}$ (which should be $1$) as well as $u(x,y)$ itself for $x,y\in[0,1)^d$. My problem is that I don't know how I should compute $u(x,y)$ in a numeric stable way. For example: While $u$ is symmetric and hence the fraction $u(x,y)$ should be equal to $u(y,x)$, I've encountered them to be dramatically off (their distance being greater than $1e5$).

Currently I'm computing $\psi$ via

```
template<typename T = double>
auto wrapped_normal_distribution_density(T x, T mu = 0, T sigma, T epsilon)
{
    T s = normal_distribution_density(x, mu, sigma);
    for (int k = 1;; ++k)
    {
        T a = normal_distribution_density(x + k, mu, sigma),
            b = normal_distribution_density(x - k, mu, sigma);
        s += a + b;
        if (a < epsilon && b < epsilon)
            break;
    }
    return s;
}

template<typename T = double>
auto normal_distribution_density(T x, T mu = 0, T sigma)
{
    auto const y = (x - mu) / sigma;
    return 1 / (sigma * std::sqrt(2 * pi<T>)) * std::exp(-y * y / 2);
}
```

Comment: @Xi'an Did you mean $x\in(0,1)$ or something else?

Comment: @Xi'an Well, then the only case where it is not positive is $x=0$, isn't it? So, even when $\beta=0$, $u(x,y)$ is not positive only when $x=y$. What exactly do you think might worry me?

Comment: @Xi'an Oh, now I got what you mean. Note that $\psi$ is well-defined even for all $x\in\mathbb R$. My intention was to restrict it to the domain that matters for the question and I messed up doing that as you noted.

Comment: @Xi'an No, it should not. I'm using $u$ as a proposal kernel. So, each proposal is samled from the density $u(x,\;\cdot\;)$ for some $x\in[0,1)^d$.

Comment: @Xi'an $\psi$ doesn't need to be a density, but $[0,1)\ni y\mapsto\psi(x-y)$ does and certainly is.